# Using Like command in SQL to determine same commodity is being sent on next service call

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-like

Currently we are trying to pull data can show us - What were the parts sent in previous service and are they the same parts or additional parts added.

I am categorizing:

Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard only - Same Part Dispatch
Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard, Display, Hard Drive - Standby Parts
Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has LCD, Hard Drive - Non Original Order

For achieving this, I am using the following CTE:

```
,CTE4 as
(
Select distinct *
, case when [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])) 

then 1 else 0 end as'Same Part Repeat'
  , case When isnull([Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List], '') = '' or isnull([Original Order], '') = '' then 1 else 0 end as 'Labor Only Repeat'
  , Case When [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] != ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])) then 1 else 0 end as 'Non Original Order'
  , Case When [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] like Concat ('%',ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])),'%') then 1 else 0 end as 'Standby Flag'
  from Dispatch_Map
  where Row_Count = 1
  )
```

But I am not getting the desired result:

The current Scenario is showing as:

Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard, Display, Hard Drive - Standby Parts
Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard only - Same Part Dispatch

Are being categorized as Non Original Order

Can you please help in getting the correct result.

Actual Code attached here for reference. Some of the reference are blanked due to our company policy.

```
With CTE1 As
(
SELECT distinct
c.[FISCAL_YEAR]
,c.[FISCAL_Quarter]
,c.[FISCAL_Month]
,c.[FISCAL_Week]
,a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
,f.[B2C_FLG]
,f.[B2D_FLG]
,d.[RGN_DESC]
,d.[SUB_RGN_DESC]
,d.[AREA_DESC]
,d.[CTRY_DESC]
,e.[LOB_DESC]
,e.[PROD_LN_DESC]
,a.[SVC_BU_ID]
,a.[SVC_ACTN_CD]
,a.[CURR_STAT]
,a.[ASST_ID]
,a.[SYS_ITM_CLS_CD]
,a.[CUST_NBR]
,a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_NBR]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_BU_ID]
,a.[PROB_DESC]
,a.[CRT_SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]
,f.[REPEAT_TM_GAP_SECND] / 86400 as 'REPEAT_TM_GAP_DAY'
,f.[REPEAT_DSPCH_NBR]
,a.[TMZN_LOC_ID]
,b.[BUS_RPTG_TEAM_NM]
,b.[ASSOC_FULL_NM]
,g.[CONTRACT_ACTIVE]
      FROM [RD].[PKG].[DH_FT] a LEFT OUTER JOIN [RD].[PKG].[A_D] b
      on
      a.[CRT_SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]=b.[SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]
      Left Outer Join [RD].[C_W].[F_D_C] C
      on a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT] = c.[ACTUAL_DATE]
      left outer join [RD].[PKG].[P_G_H_D_V] d
      on a.[SVC_BU_ID] = d.[BU_ID]
      left outer join [RD].[PKG].[B_P_H_D] e
      on
      a.[SYS_ITM_CLS_CD] = e.[ITM_CLS_CODE]
      left outer join [RD].[PKG].[G_M_R_F] f
      on
      a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] = f.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
      left outer join [GD].[o].[IB] g
      on a.[ASST_ID] = g.[ASST_ID]


  where [SVC_ACTN_CD] in (--Blanked due to data sensitivity)
  and a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] is not null
  and [CURR_STAT] not in (--Blanked due to data sensitivity)
  and d.[SUB_RGN_DESC] != '--Blanked due to data sensitivity'
  and f.[B2C_FLG] = 1
  and c.[FISCAL_Week] > = '--Blanked due to data sensitivity'
  and a.[TMZN_LOC_ID] in (--Blanked due to data sensitivity)
  )
  , CTE2 As
  (
  Select a.*
  ,b.[ITM_NBR]
  ,d.[COMMODITY_DESC]

   from CTE1 a left outer join [RD].[S_P].[G_S_D_I_O_D] b
   on a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] = b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] 
   left outer join [RD].[S].[C_M_I] c
   on
   b.[ITM_NBR] = c.[ITEM_NUM]
   left outer join [RD].[C_W].[R_C] d
   on
   c.[REPORTING_COMMODITY_ID] = d.[REPORTING_COMMODITY_ID]
   )
,CTE3 AS
(
select 
 a.[FISCAL_YEAR]
,a.[FISCAL_Quarter]
,a.[FISCAL_Month]
,a.[FISCAL_Week]
,a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
,a.[B2C_FLG]
,a.[B2D_FLG]
,a.[RGN_DESC]
,a.[SUB_RGN_DESC]
,a.[AREA_DESC]
,a.[CTRY_DESC]
,a.[LOB_DESC]
,a.[PROD_LN_DESC]
,a.[SVC_BU_ID]
,a.[SVC_ACTN_CD]
,a.[CURR_STAT]
,a.[ASST_ID]
,a.[SYS_ITM_CLS_CD]
,a.[CUST_NBR]
,a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_NBR]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_BU_ID]
,a.[PROB_DESC]
,Stuff (
(
SELECT 
                 ','+' '+ [COMMODITY_DESC]
                 FROM CTE2 b
                 WHERE 
                 b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] = a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
                 ORDER BY 
                 b.[COMMODITY_DESC] DESC
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS 'PN_Combo'

,a.[CRT_SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]
,a.[REPEAT_TM_GAP_DAY]
,a.[REPEAT_DSPCH_NBR]
,a.[TMZN_LOC_ID]
,a.[BUS_RPTG_TEAM_NM]
,a.[ASSOC_FULL_NM]
,a.[CONTRACT_ACTIVE]

from CTE2 A

group by
a.[FISCAL_YEAR]
,a.[FISCAL_Quarter]
,a.[FISCAL_Month]
,a.[FISCAL_Week]
,a.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
,a.[B2C_FLG]
,a.[B2D_FLG]
,a.[RGN_DESC]
,a.[SUB_RGN_DESC]
,a.[AREA_DESC]
,a.[CTRY_DESC]
,a.[LOB_DESC]
,a.[PROD_LN_DESC]
,a.[SVC_BU_ID]
,a.[SVC_ACTN_CD]
,a.[CURR_STAT]
,a.[ASST_ID]
,a.[SYS_ITM_CLS_CD]
,a.[CUST_NBR]
,a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_NBR]
,a.[ORIG_ORD_BU_ID]
,a.[PROB_DESC]
,a.[CRT_SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]
,a.[REPEAT_TM_GAP_DAY]
,a.[REPEAT_DSPCH_NBR]
,a.[TMZN_LOC_ID]
,a.[BUS_RPTG_TEAM_NM]
,a.[ASSOC_FULL_NM]
,a.[CONTRACT_ACTIVE]
)
,Dispatch_Map AS
  (
  select distinct
   d.[FISCAL_YEAR]
  ,d.[FISCAL_Quarter]
  ,d.[FISCAL_Month]
  ,d.[FISCAL_Week]
  ,a.[RGN_DESC]
  ,a.[SUB_RGN_DESC]
  ,a.[AREA_DESC]
  ,a.[CTRY_DESC]
  ,a.[LOB_DESC]
  ,a.[PROD_LN_DESC]
  ,a.[ASST_ID]
  ,b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID]
  ,b.[X_ISP_REPEAT_REAS_VAL]
  ,a.[PN_Combo] AS 'Original Order'
  ,b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] 
  ,b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT] 
  ,b.[SVC_ACTN_CD]
  ,c.[BUS_RPTG_TEAM_NM]
  ,c.[ASSOC_FULL_NM]
  ,DATEDIFF(day,lag(a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT],0) over (Partition by a.[ASST_ID] Order by a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]),b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]) as 'Duration'
  ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] ORDER BY b.[SVC_DSPCH_ID] ) AS 'Row_Count'
  ,Case 
  When a.[SVC_ACTN_CD] in ('OWCN','OW5') then 'P&L'
  When a.[SVC_ACTN_CD] in ('OWPCN','OWP') then 'Parts only'
  When a.[SVC_ACTN_CD] in ('BILCIS3BD(RC)','BILCIS6BD(RC)','BILCIS4BD(RC)') then 'CIS'
  When a.[SVC_ACTN_CD] in ('POR','PABILCAR') then 'CAR'
  When a.[SVC_ACTN_CD] in ('BILMIS') then 'MIS'
  Else 'Other' End as 'GSD Tower'
  ,Case
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'LCD Panel' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'LCD' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation, Battery (Notebook)' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, LCD Panel, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'LCD Panel' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Memory' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Keyboard, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation, Battery (Notebook)' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard(2), Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation, Chassis' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'LCD Panel, Chassis, Chassis' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'LCD Panel, Chassis(2)' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation, Chassis' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Motherboard, Documentation, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Fan Assembly, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentation, Cables' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Keyboard, Chassis, Chassis, Chassis, Cables' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Documentation, Battery (Notebook)' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) = 'Motherboard, Miscellaneous, Mechanical Hardware, Documentations' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) like '%Motherboard, Documentation%' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Motherboard, Documentation' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) like '%Hard Drive%' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Hard Drive' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) like '%Chassis%' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'Chassis' Then 1
   when ltrim(Rtrim(a.[PN_Combo])) like '%LCD Panel%' and b.[Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = 'LCD Panel' Then 1

   Else 0 End as 'Exemption'  

  from CTE3 a inner join [GSEDATA].[dbo].[UPSELL_FACT] b
  on 
  a.[ASST_ID] = b.[ASST_ID]
  LEFT OUTER JOIN [RAWDATA].[PARTY_PKG].[ASSOC_DIM] c
  on
  b.[SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]= c.[SRC_PRSN_HIST_GEN_ID]
  Left Outer Join [RAWDATA].[CORP_WW].[FISCAL_DAY_CALENDAR] d
  on 
  b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT] = d.[ACTUAL_DATE]

  where a.[CONTRACT_ACTIVE] = 0
  and
 b.[FISCAL_Week] >= '--Blanked due to data sensitivity'
 and 
 b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT] > a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]
 and
b.[B2D_FLG] = 1
and
a.[ASST_ID] != '--Blanked due to data sensitivity'
and
b.[DSPCH_CRT_DT] > a.[DSPCH_CRT_DT]
  )
  ,CTE4 as
  (
  Select distinct *
  , case when [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] = ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])) then 1 else 0 end as'Same Part Repeat'
  , case When isnull([Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List], '') = '' or isnull([Original Order], '') = '' then 1 else 0 end as 'Labor Only Repeat'
  , Case When [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] != ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])) then 1 else 0 end as 'Non Original Order'
  , Case When [Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List] like Concat ('%',ltrim(Rtrim([Original Order])),'%') then 1 else 0 end as 'Standby Flag'
  from Dispatch_Map
  where Row_Count = 1
  ) 
  Select *
  ,Case
   When ([Same Part Repeat] = 1 or [Exemption] = 1) and [X_ISP_REPEAT_REAS_VAL] = 'DOA Service Part' then 'DOA Repeat'
   When ([Same Part Repeat] = 1 or [Exemption] = 1) and ([X_ISP_REPEAT_REAS_VAL] != 'DOA Service Part' or isnull([X_ISP_REPEAT_REAS_VAL], '') = '') then 'Same Part Repeat'   
   When [Labor Only Repeat] = 1 and [Same Part Repeat] = 0 and [Exemption] = 0 then 'Labor Only Repeat'
   When [Same Part Repeat] = 0 and [Labor Only Repeat] = 0 and [Standby Flag] = 0 and [Non Original Order] = 1 and [Exemption] = 0 then 'Non Original Order'
   When [Standby Flag] = 1 and [Non Original Order] = 1 and [Same Part Repeat] = 0 and [Labor Only Repeat] = 0 and [Exemption] = 0 then 'Standby Parts'
   Else 'Others' End as 'Part Repeat Cause'

   from CTE4
```

Results as currently being shown

[image]

Blue Underlined should be shown as Standby Parts where as showing as Non original order

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I did not understand your request. The scenarios is what I have explained

Comment: I'm requesting sample data (as create table(s) and insert into statements) and desired results.

Comment: I am giving an example here :Customer A purchased Motherboard and Heat sink but the issue could not be resolved. He was sent Display kit and Processor.

Comment: The code that i am trying to build is to check if Customer A received the same parts that he ordered earlier or there were new parts sent

Comment: The challenge i am facing is - When i use the CTE code - It is not giving me the right answer. The current Senario showing as Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard, Display, Hard Drive - Standby Parts Ser 1 has Motherboard, Documentation and Ser 2 has Motherboard only - Same Part Dispatch

Comment: Look, you can do whatever you want, I really don't care. I'm trying to help you - but you don't have to listen.

Comment: It looks like your list of ordered products is a comma separated string inside one column and the same for shipped products. What a mess, as long as you don't re-design the database its always going to be a lot of trouble (almost impossinble) to check what has been delivered specially since it's all free text and not product id and you also seems to have incorporated the number of items as well in the column.

Comment: What is the logic behind your attempt?   Of course you are getting these results, for those rows the `Original Order` value is not LIKE the `Dispatch_Part_Commodity_List`.   What is the rule you are trying to follow to get your desired results?   It's not clear from your non-working code.

Comment: The logic of my attempt is find wether we are sending the same part of that of the original order. If we add part to the original order it should be Stand By parts , if we send completely different part it should be non original order. But what it is displaying is that even same part is sent for example if the Original order had Motherboard,documentation and next order has Motherboard it is showing Non Orignal order - where as it should have said Same Order.

Comment: Second Example - if Part sent in Original order was Hard Drive, LCD but follow up order was LCD and motherboard - this should be coded as standby parts but showing as Non original order. This what I am looking T code to be corrected

Comment: Don't do this in sql, do it in the client code instead where you ,hopefully, can work with arrays or other collection types and loops etc to compare the columns.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson hmm. Unfortunately I am not sophisticated on that